# Why is the local content different from the remote content after clone a project with Github in Android Studio 3.5.3?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I clone a project with Github from https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/tree/1.0.0-alpha08 in Android Studio 3.5.3.

The web URL is https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples.git

I'm very strange why the local content is different from remote content.

The remote content is located at https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/blob/1.0.0-alpha08/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle

The remote code is `def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha08"`, you can see Image 1.

The local code is `def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha06"`, you can see Image 2.

What's matter with me?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you got the repository? I suspect it was

```
git clone https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples.git
```

and you got the **master** branch. In `master` the [code is `def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha06"`](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/blob/3d1a254eb018a51ff39ae78d39a9e9e7942a027b/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle#L86)

To get to the branch [`1.0.0-alpha08`](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/blob/7cf22adbe6a2b3b5f1b3f2e79049926b69a19f80/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle#L87) you need to switch [branches](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/branches):

```
git checkout 1.0.0-alpha08
```

or its equivalent in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks! I need to switch to the branch 1.0.0-alpha08 after clone